# How to return dictionary with each result printed on a new line using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to print my dictionary with each result on a new line like this:

```
    {"less than high school":0.10202002459160373,
    "high school":0.172352011241876,
    "more than high school but not college":0.24588090637625154,
    "college":0.47974705779026877}
```

But the code I wrote prints an output that looks like this:

```
{'less than high school': 0.10202002459160373, 'high school': 0.172352011241876, 'more than high school but not college': 0.24588090637625154, 'college': 0.47974705779026877}
```

I'm thinking about adding a regex but I'm not sure if it would be appropriate here. Any suggestions would be really appreciated!

```
def proportion_of_education():
    # importing pandas as pd
    import pandas as pd

    # importing numpyt as np
    import numpy as np

    # reading csv file as a pandas dataframe (df)
    df = pd.read_csv("assets/NISPUF17.csv", index_col=0)

    # pulling values in variable EDUC1
    m_educ=df['EDUC1']

    # sorting through EDUC1 values
    m_val=np.sort(m_educ.values)

    # defining dictionary
    dict={"less than high school":0,
          "high school":0,
          "more than high school but not college":0,
          "college":0
           }

    # equation for defining proportion 
    tot = len(m_val)

    # applying conditions
    dict["less than high school"]=np.sum(m_val==1)/tot
    dict["high school"]=np.sum(m_val==2)/tot
    dict["more than high school but not college"]=np.sum(m_val==3)/tot
    dict["college"]=np.sum(m_val==4)/tot

# printing dict to display proportion results
    print (dict)
    return proportion_of_education()
    raise NotImplementedError()
    
proportion_of_education()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

**1 - Iterate trough your dict and print each key/value**

```
for item in myDict.items():
    print(*item)
```

Output:

```
less than high school 0.10202002459160373
high school 0.172352011241876
more than high school but not college 0.24588090637625154
college 0.47974705779026877
```

Or similar (unpacking item into key/value):

```
for key, value in t.items():
    print(f"{key}: {value}")
```

Output:

```
less than high school: 0.10202002459160373
high school: 0.172352011241876
more than high school but not college: 0.24588090637625154
college: 0.47974705779026877
```

**2 - Utilize python lib `pprint` which has a `pformat` build in method**

```
from pprint import pformat
print(pformat(myDict))
```

Output:

```
{'college': 0.47974705779026877,
 'high school': 0.172352011241876,
 'less than high school': 0.10202002459160373,
 'more than high school but not college': 0.24588090637625154}
```

If the order matters:

```
print(pformat(myDict, sort_dicts=False))
```

Comment: What does 't' and 'f' represent?

Comment: Typo, ```t``` (myDict) is your dictionary.

Comment: The ```f``` is a formatting format in python see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/